# No * candidates produce the expected result type FloatingPointRoundingRule

Tags: ios, swift3, rounding

In Swift 3 I am getting the following error (which wasn't happening in Swift 2):

> No * candidates produce the expected result type
>   FloatingPointRoundingRule

I don't know what I need to do to fix it.

I am trying to convert latitude decimal to degrees/minutes/seconds

```
extension CLLocationDegrees {        
    mutating func toLatitudeSeconds() -> String {
        var seconds = Int(round(self * 3600)) //error here
        // etc ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The rounding functions were changed to be called on an instance rather than being global functions.  You're basically trying to do `self.round(self*3600)` which doesn't work because the `round` function takes either no argument or an argument of type `FloatingPointRoundingRule`.

You probably want:

```
var seconds = Int((self*3600).rounded())
```

Comment: I really wish they would stop making changes like this with every major version update to swift, pick a way and stay with it. Sorry for the mini rant your answer worked thanks

Comment: They did this for `round` but why not `ceil` and `floor`...?

Comment: @shim They probably want you to use `round` instead of `ceil` and `floor`.  e.g. `x.round(.up)` and `x.round(.down)`

Comment: Did you mean `rounded(.up)` and `.down`?